# How Validate Id is correct before creating file using makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to Validate the ID with pattern (Abbbbb-yyy)

Example :

```
ID := A12345-789 B98765-123 C58730-417
VARIANT := test1 test2 test3
```

Build and post processing will generate files depends up on VARIANTS :

```
`sw_main_test1.hex ,sw_main_test1.hex and sw_main_test1.hex  `

.PHONY : SW_TEST
SW_TEST :
    if <ID is correct>
    cp sw_main_test1.hex --> A12345-789.hex 
    cp sw_main_test2.hex --> B98765-123.hex
    cp sw_main_test3.hex --> C58730-417.hex
```

I am facing issue in validating the ID with pattern

```
`Abbbbb-yyy.txt`
```

Where : `A=[A-Z]; b=[0-9]; y=[0-9]`

Please let me know how to verify ID is correct using regular expressions inside the Makefile using any tool or utility

Comment: How one would do that, depends on some other factors. Are the files targets themself, or are they just generated, while a different target is build as a byproduct? If the files are targets themself, I assume your makefile is generated itself, how are you doing this? Please read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I recommend delegating the name-testing to a script. What scripting languages are you comfortable with?

Comment: @Beta : I am comfortable with python

Comment: Where does the data (`ID`) come from? From a file?

Answer (score 0):

In this script, I assume, you get your ID from a file (I called it here `someidcontent.txt`). Then you could write a script like this (assuming, you only working on Linux).

```
getID = $(shell cat someidcontent.txt)

all:
   if [ "$(getID)" == "1234567890" ]; then \
       cp -v output.txt ./delivery/$(getID).txt; \
   fi

.PHONY: all
```

**Edit**

I made a mistake in my previous script. I did not check, if the ID is correct. Now my newer script does this: I read from a file the ID and check it for correctness. If ID is correct, then some file will be copied into target dir with ID number.

```
# get ID from a file
getID := $(shell cat someidcontent.txt)
# need a hack for successful checking
idToCheck := $(getID)

# check procedure
checkID := $(shell echo $(idToCheck) | grep "[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]$$")

all:
ifeq "$(checkID)" "$(idToCheck)"
   echo found
   cp -v output.txt ./delivery/$(idToCheck).txt;
endif

.PHONY: all
```

**Edit 2**

Ok, this was a little bit challenging, but I solved it somehow. Maybe there are also other ways to solve this better. In my solution, I assume that the file with IDs and source filenames look like this (in other words, this is the content of my `someidcontent.txt`):

```
A2345-678:output1.txt
B3456-123:output.txt
C0987-987:thirdfile.txt
```

And this is my makefile with comments for additional explanation. I hope, they are sufficient

```
# retrieve id and filename data from other file
listContent := $(shell cat someidcontent.txt)

# extract only IDs from other files
checkIDs = $(shell echo $(listContent) | grep -o "[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]")

all:
# iterate only over IDs
# first, give me the ID
# second retrieve the filename part for successful copy procedure
# and copy the file to the target dir with ID as filename
   @$(foreach x,$(checkIDs), \
      echo $(x); \
      cp -v $(shell echo $(listContent) | grep -o "$(x):[A-Z0-9a-z\.]*" | sed "s/[-A-Z0-9]*://g") ./delivery/$(x).t$
   )

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: Kristain your answer is good but the It will work if we have single ID and single output file if we have list of IDS and list of output files it will fail

Comment: @Vicky: Is there a way how to determine which output file belongs to which ID?

Comment: @kristain its sequence first ID list element corresponds to first VARIANT list element

Comment: @Vicky I've made an edit to my solution. I hope, this can help you to create the `Makefile` you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can check simple string patterns quite ok (don't want to say "nicely") from within make:

```
[A-F] := A B C D E F#
[a-f] := a b c d e f#
[A-Z] := $([A-F]) G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z#
[a-z] := $([a-f]) g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z#
[0-9] := 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9#

######################################################################
##### $(call explode,_stringlist_,_string_)
## Insert a blank after every occurrence of the strings from _stringlist_ in _string_.
## This function serves mainly to convert a string into a list.
## Example: `$(call explode,0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,0xl337c0de)` --> `0 xl3 3 7 c0 de`
explode = $(if $1,$(subst $(firstword $1),$(firstword $1) ,$(call explode,$(wordlist 2,255,$1),$2)),$2)


ID := A12345-789 B98765-123 C58730-417 123456+328

############################################################
# $(call check-id,_id-string_)
# Return 'malformed' or the given id
check-id = $(if $(call check-id-1,$(call explode,- $([A-Z]) $([0-9]),$1)),malformed,$1)
check-id-1 = $(strip $(filter-out $([A-Z]),$(wordlist 1,1,$1)) $(filter-out $([0-9]),$(wordlist 2,6,$1)) $(filter-out -,$(word 7,$1)) $(filter-out $([0-9]),$(wordlist 8,10,$1)) )

$(info $(foreach w,$(ID),$(call check-id,$(w))))
```